# How To Check checked value of a checkbox using Reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I've got a React web app using bootstrap 4 and Reactstrap.  I want to have several checkboxes in a toolbar and I can't figure out how to get anything out of the onChange event besides "on".

Here is my code that continues to write "on" to the console every time I click the checkbox.  The checkbox does toggle on and off.

```
     <li className="show-sessions">
        <FormGroup check>
          <Label check>
            <Input
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
            />{" "}
            <strong>Show Favorites</strong>
          </Label>
        </FormGroup>
      </li>
```

Is there another way to make a checkbox in Reactstrap? The doc's are very limited.

Answer (score 7):

you can check `checked` state rather than `value`; it is a `boolean`

```
<Input
  type="checkbox"
  onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.checked)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Leonardo, is there a more "reactstrap/bootstrap" way to get a styled checkbox out? This one is not in align and I'm totally not a css or bootstrap person. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rc07wozvdxstnk/checkboxugly.png?dl=0